# How do I run map/reduce on files in local file system?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How do I run a Java map/reduce job on files available in local file system? For instance, I have a 3 node cluster, and all the nodes have a log file in their local file system, say /home/log/log.txt.

How do I run a job on these files? Do I need to combine them and transfer it to HDFS before running the job?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload all the individual files under one folder and provide that folder path as input path to your map reduce program. Your Map Reduce runs on all the files in that folder.

Comment: Thanks. But if the files are very large then it will cause problems when I move all the files to a single system. And if there are more than 3 nodes, it is going to be even more difficult. Is there any way to run it directly without having to move the files?

Comment: You can use below hadoop command from your linux terminal to place the file into hdfs.

hadoop fs -put <localfilepath> <hdfsdirectorypath>